# What is the proper PHP way to include variable_1, variable_2, variable_3 when enclosed between ' '

Tags: php, syntax, indexing, while-loop

I received the following error for a while-loop:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING

```
$index=1;
while ($index <= 100):

fwrite($outfile, $_POST[\'"variable_" . $index\']);
fwrite($outfile, "\r");


$index = $index + 1;
endwhile;
fclose($outfile);
?>
```

What is the proper way to include variable_1, variable_2, variable_3 without getting syntax error?

Thanks.

Comment: use `if (!array_key_exists("variable_{$index}", $_POST) { continue ; }` just before using your `$_POST["variable_{$index}"]` variable, just in case it wasn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = "variable_$index";
fwrite($outfile, $_POST[$x]);
```

I'd consider using a for loop here as well.

```
// Assuming you open $outfile somewhere prior to this
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ ) {
    $x = "variable_$i";
    fwrite($outfile, $_POST[$x]);
    fwrite($outfile, "\r");
} 
fclose($outfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your quotes mixed up - you don't need the \' parts:

`$_POST["variable_" . $index]`

Answer (score 0):

there was mistake in `single` and `double` quotes

```
fwrite($outfile, $_POST["'variable_" . $index."'"]);
```

Comment: The extra single quotes are not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite($outfile, implode("\r", array_values($_POST)));
```

Comment: This is assuming that *all* of the $_POST variables need to be printed out.